# Strange problem with Cycles Normal Map baking

Tags: cycles-render-engine, normals, texture-baking

I am trying to bake a normal map with Cycles, but no matter what I try, the results are always strange, and I am at my wit's end.

I keep getting weird results like this:
[image: https://s18.postimg.org/aq2e7tt21/Head_N.png]

These are my bake settings:

[image: https://s9.postimg.org/i7g76f6zz/Screenshot_20160915_230505.png]

High-Poly model:

[image: High-Poly]

Low-Poly model:

[image: Low-Poly]

Any and all help much appreciated! This model is a project for a game development college course I am studying, just to clarify. :)

Comment: High-poly model: https://s15.postimg.org/vizivkgbf/Screenshot_20160915_225621.png

Comment: Low-poly model: https://s12.postimg.org/wcpyasgkd/Screenshot_20160915_225549.png

Comment: Did you used smooth shading? it might fix the problem

Comment: @KyleDe'Vir - please don't add image links as comments. You can easily edit your question and add them there.

Comment: @metaphor_set Below 10 rep, you can't post more than 2 images :)

Comment: @ShadyPuck - I know. I was referring to the links in the comments. There's nothing wrong with editing the question and adding the links there.

Answer (score 1):

You need to activate smooth shading for your low-poly model.

Select your model, go to "Tool Shelf - Tools - Edit - Shading" and hit the "Smooth" button.

[image: smooth shading]